# Top vertical align div css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I don't know the height of parent element. 
I aligned child div vertically using:

```
position:  absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

How can I align div in the same way in top10%-part? Child div should start after 10% of parent div vertically.

```css
.text-image.flag {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: right;
  right: -5px;
  background: url(/flag.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<td class="firstColumn wide-cell index-cell tall-cell sorting_1">
  <div class="inner-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="table-tooltip" index="7">
      <a href="">
        <div class="text-image">
          Real, Student
        </div>
        <div class="text-image flag"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I want to have top 10% from `firstColumn`, not from inner-wrapper.

Comment: Please add more details about what you are looking for and add your HTML markup so we can help you.

Comment: Writing position:absolute; top:10%; should do it

Comment: @cornel.raiu top will not work if parent height is not defined

Comment: Yes, top doesn’t work. Parent doesn’t have a height

Comment: I need the same as I wrote above, but not the center alignment, but top 10%

Comment: please add more details then including the html of your parent-child items + the css of both parent and child

Comment: @cornel.raiu done

Comment: Can't you use margin-top: 10%?

Comment: I can't use it because of nearest parent has relative position

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `<div id="container>` around all of the relevant code, and style it like `position: relative;` so you can use `position: absolute;` on the child div, because absolute positioning only works if its parent is not statically positioned.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you.

```css
.parent {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}
.child {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
  This is content.
 </div>
</div>
```